# Best way to load objects in batches

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform

In my iOS app users can make a post so other users can view it along other posts.
Now I ran into an issue in the logic of fetching old and new posts after the initial fetch.

So currently when a user opens the Posts View Controller this is the method that gets called to fetch the last 40 posts near his location (I am using parse SDK and parse backend server)

```
+(NSArray*)fetchLatestPostsNearLocation:(PFGeoPoint*) location
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query setLimit:40];
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:location];
[query includeKey:@"poster"];
 NSSortDescriptor* sorter=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[query orderBySortDescriptor:sorter];
return  [query findObjects];
}
```

Lets say the user reaches the last post and would like to fetch older posts , how would I do that?

I am thinking about using the date in my query but I am not sure how
or should I introduce a sequence field in the posts model and fetch based on that field (even though I don't think this is the right way to do it).
Also , how would I load newer posts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you'd need to find the oldest post (since you are showing some sort of timeline I assume you are already sorting them by date). Keep the oldest date (e.g: `oldestDate`) and then query another batch using `whereKey:lessThan:`

```
Date *oldestDate = ...


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query setLimit:40];
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:location];
[query includeKey:@"poster"];
[query orderByDescending:@"date"];
[query whereKey:@"date" lessThan:oldestDate]; // Get it from function param, check if-nil to only have 1 method for loading & pagination, if possible

return  [query findObjects];

// Append new posts to model data, reload tableview/collectionview
```

You could also (benchmarking needed):

- Use `createdAt`/`updatedAt` of the last post you downloaded.
- Use `limit`/`skip` instead of `whereKey:lessThan:`